# If $|f| \leq e^{1/|z|^2}$ for every $z\in G$...

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $G = \{z| Im(z)>0\}$, and $f \in Hol(G)$.
>
> If $|f| \leq e^{1/|z|^2}$ for every $z\in G$ then we have $ f\equiv_{|_G}0$

The teacher gave an hint but it is still a hard question , and I just got stuck...

The hint: Take big enough real number R>0 and big enough natural number N and define $g(z)=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} f(e^{2\pi i k /N}z+iR)$ in $D_R=\{z\ |\  |z|<R \}$

Comment: My guess is that you're supposed to use [Rouché's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem).

Comment: @SpamIAm I thought using the identity theorem, but I have no real clue what to do (also with Rouche I have no real direction)

Comment: @SpamIAm The lecturer explaned to me the concept of the proof , it is not simple , and though I think I understood the solution, I didn't understand it enough to explain it(He used the geometric interpretation of g(z) and the formula for length of a chord)